# Symfony Twig : get Object property with a variable property

Tags: symfony, variables, object, attributes, twig

Symfony 3.0 :

In my project, I have many entities which contain more than 50 fields, so for the twig which shows every entity, I decided to automate the display of the 50 fields by a simple loop.

First problem: how to get entity's all fields names, I resolved this by creating a custom twig filter:

```
<?php
// src/HomeBundle/Twig/HomeExtension.php
namespace HomeBundle\Twig;

class HomeExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('object_keys', array($this, 'getObjectKeys')),
        );
    }

    public function getObjectKeys($object)
    {
        //Instantiate the reflection object
        $reflector = new \ReflectionClass( get_class($object) );

        //Now get all the properties from class A in to $properties array
        $properties = $reflector->getProperties();
        $result=array();
        foreach ($properties as $property)
            $result[] = $property->getName();

        return $result;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_extension';
    }
}

?>
```

The second problem which generates the error right now is: how to access object properties within a loop:

```
{% for property in article|object_keys%}
    <tr>
        <th>
            {{property|capitalize}}
            {# that's work clean #}
        </th>
        <td>
            {{ attribute(article,property) }}
            {# that's generate the error #}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

The error :

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
> ("Notice: Array to string conversion"). 500 Internal Server Error -
> Twig_Error_Runtime

**Finally,** the error is fixed on the `getObjectKeys` method of the filter,

so when it returns an array that I create manually it works:

```
return array("reference","libelle");
```

But, when I send an array created within a loop => Error.

I dumped the two arrays in the twig, they were equivalents, but the second still generating an error.

Comment: One of your properties is returning an array rather than a string value

Comment: @DarkBee : Good reasoning my friend, I have some object fields .
So what you suggest in my situation ?
Should i create for every entity a method that returns an array containing the entities properties names associated to there values ( manually).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely one of your properties is returning an array rather than a simple `string`, `integer`, `...`. A solution here could be to store the value in a variable and check whether the stored value is an array. Depending on that check do something with the value or otherwise just output the variable

```
{% for property in article|object_keys%}
<tr>
    <th>
        {{property|capitalize}}
    </th>
    <td> 
        {% set value = attribute(article,property) %}
        {% if value is iterable %}{# test if value is an array #}
            {{ value | join(', ') }}
        {% else %}
            {{ value }}
        {% endif %}
    </td>
</tr>                   
{% endfor%}
```